# React Native crashes in release mode

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native run-android --variant=release` it is continuously crashing without any errors on both the simulator and mobile phone.

I tried the suggestions in [this article](https://medium.com/@impaachu/react-native-android-release-build-crash-on-device-14f2c9eacf18) but when I run `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease` it gives this error:

```
> Task :react-native-navigation:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:verifyReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  /Users/balwindersingh/Desktop/WEBSITETOON/teamwallpaper/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  /Users/balwindersingh/Desktop/WEBSITETOON/teamwallpaper/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  /Users/balwindersingh/Desktop/WEBSITETOON/teamwallpaper/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:3083: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/balwindersingh/Desktop/WEBSITETOON/teamwallpaper/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:3084: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s

180 actionable tasks: 168 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably that you are building your app with sdkVersion 28 while react-navigation uses an older version.

You could overwrite the version in your `android/build.gradle` file:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion "$buildToolsVersion"
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

(I am not sure whether this is the best way though...)

Alternatively you could fork react-navigation and change the version in their `android/app/build.gradle` file to `28`.

Comment: How do I see my react navigation version?

Comment: check your package.json file. there should be a line with `"react-navigation": '''<version>"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the drawable folders in your res folder. if you followed that article then deleting those drawable folders causing the error. try without deleting drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had left a console.log() statement in app therefore it was running completely fine on  debug mode but crashed on release mode. After digging my mind in, I realized that it was this small problem.
So do check your app pages as well for such minor problems.